# CKAN - Find and add tags to multiple datasets can this be done?

Tags: api, ckan

I want to add a tag "Water" to any dataset that includes data "agua"

Can I use the API to search, find and update all datasets that contain the search string "agua" to add a tag "Water"

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can search all datasets that contain the word "agua" using the `package_search` API action, eg http://demo.ckan.org/api/3/action/package_search?q=agua

Once you have them you can either:

- For each of the returned results, add the "Water" tag and call the [`package_update`](http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/api/index.html#ckan.logic.action.update.package_update) action (sending the whole package object, not just the tag)
- For each of the returned results, call the [`package_patch`](http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/api/index.html#ckan.logic.action.patch.package_patch) action, sending the updated tags (make sure to include the existing ones), eg :

  `{"tags": [{"name": "Water"}, {"name": "OtherTag"}]}`

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you amercader for the response.  Still very new at this and could use additional help using the API.


Completed 1st step easy https://data.amerigeoss.org/api/3/action/package_search?q=agua finds 1503 packages/resources.


Now how do I  "append" = add additional tags called "water" and "environment" to the current list of tags in each of the 1503 results keeping the existing tags adding the 2 additional tags.

Would you give me an example of how to add the tags calling each of the actions package_search-->package_update-->package_patch step by step?

Any help is appreciated.